# If my div is `display: none` print not working. How to change it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My div is `display: none` and printing does not work. How can I change this?

Plugin: https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/tree/master/jQuery.printElement

**html:**

```
<a href="#" value="$('#toPrint').printElement()" id="simplePrint">Print</a>

<div id="toPrint">adgsdhashdshas</div>
```

**css:**

```
#toPrint { display: none; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#simplePrint").click(function(){
        $('#toPrint').printElement();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'd have to remove the `display:none` style, as you can't print something that is'nt there?

Comment: Change the display to {visibility:hidden;} , that should alleviate it. I hope :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use print styles and set the div to display:block in that.

```
@media print
{ #toPrint { display: block; } }
```